# How to set a background for my form in c++builder6?

Tags: c++, background, c++builder

I am new to C++Builder 6, but I have used C++. My question is, how do I set a background for my form? When I open the application I want the background to have a specific image. I tried with `Graphics::TBitmap` but it says that the image is not valid even if it is bmp.

```
Graphics::TBitmap *BmpTabla = new Graphics::TBitmap;

try {
        BmpTabla->LoadFromFile("board.bmp");

}
__finally
{
    delete BmpTabla;
}
```

Edit: I just changed the picture and worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop TImage component to the form, send it to back of the all controls, set the Align property to alClient.
In runtime

```
Image1->Picture->LoadFromFile("board.bmp");
```

Comment: It worked, but now it says that "Bitmap image is not valid", there are certain standars for images?

Comment: Picture object load the file according to its type (file extension). If `.bmp` file has other format regardless the type, an exception will be thrown. Try to test some trusted bitmap file i.e. included in C++Builder distribution package. Also try to open `.bmp` in some graphic editor (GIMP, XnView...) and re-save it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to have a custom background is to use a client-aligned `TImage`, like @serge suggested.

Another way is to load the BMP image into a `Graphics::TBitmap` object (like you are already attempting to do) and then use the Form's `OnPaint` event to draw the `TBitmap` onto the Form's `Canvas`.

The "image is not valid" error means you are trying to load a `.bmp` file that is not a valid BMP image.  Double check the contents of the file.